# How to get the number of devices connected to ESP softAP?

Tags: stm32, esp8266, at-command, esp-12f

I'm using STM32 as the main microcontroller and an **ESP-12F** is connected to it via serial port. I'm controlling ESP with AT commands.

I want to figure out how many devices are connected to my ESP. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your device is acting as an access point, meaning that you previously configured it in that whay with

```
AT+CWMODE=2
```

The command for obtaining the list of stations connected to the access point is **`AT+CWLIF`**:

```
AT+CWLIF

<IP device 1>,<MAC address device 1>
<IP device 2>,<MAC address device 2>
...
<IP device N>,<MAC address device N>

OK
```

So, basically, you will get a row containing the `<IP>,<MAC address>` couple for each connected station. Counting those lines will tell you how many devices are connected to your ESP.